# Check if multiple conditions are all false or all true - java

Tags: java

This sounds simple but my mind is drawing a blank

say i have this

```
bool evaluator
for each form element{

    if (element.name = 'fname')
    {
      perform some op
      evaluator = true
    }else evaluator false


    if (element.name = 'city')
    {
      perform some op
      evaluator true
    }else evaluator false

    if (element.name='shipcity')
    {
      perform some op
      evaluator true
    }else evaluator false

}

return evaluator

where evaluator :

    if((t/f) && (t/f) && (t/f))
         |         |        |-----------------evaluation of condition 3
         |         |-----------evaluation of condition 2
         |--------------evaluation of condition 1
```

so at the end i get the '&&' of the 3 conditions. or does java have a built in method which will do this for me

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by `if((t/f) && (t/f) && (t/f))`

Comment: Can you explain your last line?--You answered your own question: if(condition1 && condition2 && condition3) {doSomethingAwesome()}

Comment: Can you clarify when the checks on `condition2` and `condition3` are supposed to occur?  The code that you posted will return after `condition1` has been checked and acted on, regardless of whether the operation associated with `condition1` is actually performed.

Answer (score 11):

```
if (cond1 == cond2 && cond2 == cond3)
```

nice and simple

Answer (score 2):

To check if multiple conditions are all false or all true:

```
if (cond1 && cond2 && cond3 || !cond1 && !cond2 && !cond3) ...
```

There are more concise ways to write this, but I think the above is clearer in expressing the intent.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP was asking for.  My reading of his/her question is that he/she wanted just `cond1 && cond2 && cond3`

Comment: @DavidWallace: I agree that the question could be much clearer. However, the title is *check if multiple conditions are **all false or all true*** (emphasis mine).

Comment: sorry.  I read the question, but not the title.  Consider my comment null and void.  I was wondering why 3 of the 4 answers that are currently here had all interpreted the question the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Extending upon's wcdolphin's comment, you can do this:

```
if(condition1 && condition2 && condition3){
   // do stuff
}
```

Note that if `condition1` (or any other embedded conditional) evaluates to false, all other following conditionals will not even be evaluated.  Where this becomes significant:

```
if(condition1() && condition2() && condition3()){
   // do stuff
}
```

If you instead made the conditionals to be method calls, for example, that could be relatively "expensive" operations - this will prevent the following functions from being called if a prior conditional evaluates to false.

The same holds true for in-line conditionals, like:

```
if((a < b) && (c < d) && (e < f)){
   // do stuff
}
```

If `a >= b`, neither `c < d` or `e < f` will ever be called, which can be a performance savings.  (This is an improvement over your first code snippet, where all 3 conditions would always be evaluated.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if they were all true OR all false, you'd do something like:

```
if ((c1 && c2 && c3) || (!c1 && !c2 && !c3)) {
  //do things
}
```

Where c1, c2, and c3 are booleans.

Hope that is what you were asking.